# Show that $G$ is group under matrix multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Following question is from one of the previous year papers. I am feeling that something is misprinted here.

[image]

Is this question correct?

Comment: What about the inverses?

Comment: Yes, this question is correct. Very strange group because the identity of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is NOT the identity of this group $G$!

Comment: @ndhanson3: Identity: $2\times2$ matrix whose every entry is $1/2$?

Comment: Yep! So now, an inverse of $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&a\\a&a\end{pmatrix}$ is a matrix $B=\begin{pmatrix}b&b\\b&b\end{pmatrix}$ such that $AB=\begin{pmatrix}1/2&1/2\\1/2&1/2\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @ndhanson3: To show existence of inverse, we need to solve equations or is there any quicker way to see that?

Comment: It's just one equation, and you solve for $b$ in terms of $a$. Think, what is the inverse of the matrix with all $5$s? With all $10$s? Now with all $a$s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just moving the comments to an answer.

Yes, this group is written correctly! However, the identity of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not the identity of $G$. You are correct that it is the matrix with entries equal to $1/2$. So now, an inverse of $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&a\\a&a\end{pmatrix}$ is a matrix $B=\begin{pmatrix}b&b\\b&b\end{pmatrix}$ such that $AB=\begin{pmatrix}1/2&1/2\\1/2&1/2\end{pmatrix}$.

Small addition: depending on the strictness of your grader, you really should show either that $G$ is an abelian group or that both $AB$ and $BA$ are equal to the matrix with $1/2$s.